# How can I access the iOS information in Settings/General/About

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In the about section of iOS it has alot of information about the device.  Can I and am I allowed to access this informtion. Like is there a single method that returns the disk space available or number of apps.

If there is not a single method available can I count the number of Apps installed.

Secondly for things like Number of photos is there a method to get this number or do I have to go into the devices photo library and count it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've searched but find that you can't read or write the device's setting. This is to protect the user(suppose that every app can change your iphone's setting). That is you can't get the number of app installed.

Code to get images count you can use `ALAssetsLibrary`

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
NSAssert(library, @"Unable to open ALAssetsLibrary");

NSUInteger __block images = 0;
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                           images += group.numberOfAssets;
                       }
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *err) {
                         NSLog(@"err=%@", err);
                     }];
NSLog("images count %d", images);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the systemUtilites class methods to retrieve the information you want. You can find description of it at this link

http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-system-utilities/908

Comment: Thanks, but I am wanting to implement this myself or use Appkit API's.